# What is the plural form of the letter A, as in the grade or mark, not the indefinite article?

Tags: plural-forms

This is a line from the tutoring job on my resume.

> Helped raise 12 students’ grades from Cs and low Bs to high Bs and A’s in multiple classes across different semesters.

Is the plural form for A correct? I think an apostrophe is needed to prevent confusion with the word "as."

Comment: You have two styles in your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the apostrophe because (i) *from Cs and low Bs to high Bs and as in multiple classes across different semesters* does not make sense and (ii) **as** has no capital letters. The apostrophe in *A's* also looks strange as you have not used it in Cs and Bs